# Run-time error 1004 while copy-pasting data

Tags: excel, macros, vba

I have written a macro to list down all the numbers between certain ranges and then to paste values against each number. The macro throws a Run-time error 1004. Here's the macro:

```
Sub Populate()
Range("A1") = Range("H18").Value
Range("A1").Select
Selection.DataSeries Rowcol:=xlColumns, Type:=xlLinear, Date:=xlDay, _
        Step:=1, Stop:=Range("I18").Value, Trend:=False

Range("J18").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("B1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    Range("B20").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlUp).Offset(-1, 0)).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Range("B1").Select

Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0) = Range("H19").Value
Range("A1").End(xlDown).Select
Selection.DataSeries Rowcol:=xlColumns, Type:=xlLinear, Date:=xlDay, _
        Step:=1, Stop:=Range("I19").Value, Trend:=False


Range("J18").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("B1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    Range("B20").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlUp).Offset(-1, 0)).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Range("B1").Select

 End Sub
```

Comment: The error occurs on which line?

Comment: Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlUp).Offset(-1, 0)).Select

Comment: The problem is that a) Selection is B20 b) Selection.End(xlUp) is B1 c) Selection.End(xlUp).Offset(-1, 0) tries to go one row above B1 and there isn't one. The [Range.Offset property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840060.aspx) uses `.Offset(row, col)`. Your code can get cleaned up quite a bit but I honestly have no idea what it is attempting to do.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I want to select B2:B20 which can dynamically change based on users. I should have used Selection.End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)  and not (-1,0). Such a silly mistake. Thanks for pointing it out. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the beginning of your syntax to:

```
Dim dRange As Range
Set dRange = Range("A1:I18")
Range("A1") = Range("H18").Value
Range("A1").Select
dRange.DataSeries Rowcol:=xlColumns, Type:=xlLinear, Date:=xlDay
```

You will probably still run into issues due to the following code being repeated:

```
Range("B20").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlUp).Offset(-1, 0)).Select
```

Not sure exactly what the end goal is with this, but from my testing this gets you closer and takes care of your `Run-time error: '1004'`

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your reply. This doesn't solve my problem. In cell H18, there is start value of a range, say '1' and in cell I18, there is end value of range, say, 20. The user enters these values and so accordingly the range can change. So it has to be dynamic. Then in J18, there is a value which needs to be pasted against each number in the list. So what the macro does is paste in cell B1 and then it should paste in cells B2 to the end of the list but it should not overwrite cell B1 and hence I tried to add  .Offset (-1,0) but it is because of which the error is thrown. Thanks!